# How to check if a button has been clicked using selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

```
def LikePhotos(self, amount):
        bot = self.bot
        #if button is being clicked then move to next pic else click then move to next pic
        if():
            print("Button has already been clicked")
        else:
            print("Button hasn't been clicked!")    
        bot.find_element_by_class_name("_9AhH0").click()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "has already been clicked"? Do you mean that the current user already "liked" the photo?

Comment: You might be able to tell if the "like" button has been previously clicked by the classes on it. I suggest you inspect the page to see if the class names have anything to do with the state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Selenium works. Selenium can send a command to the browser to click a button, but cannot check if a button was clicked by some other means.